# How to remove the "link to anchor" from the "Link" editor in CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

Basically I removed the anchor button so there should not be a link to anchor option in my link window.

Any way to remove that dropdown option

[image]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out

```
if ( dialogName == 'link' )
    {
      var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
      var linktypeField = infoTab.get( 'linkType' );

      /* Remove it from the array of items */
      linktypeField['items'].splice(1, 1);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

[dialogDefinition](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.html) allows you to completely redesign dialog boxes.

I did it this way, based on the example at http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7156/_samples/api_dialog.html

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
{
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event
    // data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
    // interested on (the "Link" dialog).
    if ( dialogName == 'link' )
    {
        // Get a reference to the "Link Info" tab.
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        infoTab.remove( 'linkType' );
    }
});

$("#mydiv").ckeditor(function(){}, {
    removeDialogTabs: 'link:advanced;link:target'
    // any other customizations go here.
});
```

Comment: Just to make sure i understand, your answer will remove the dropdown all together. So to remove only one option from the dropdown i have to remove the existing one and add a custom one?

Comment: I thought you wanted the box completely gone. I see you've figured out the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This's my solution:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
// Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
var dialogName = ev.data.name;
var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
// Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
// interested in (the 'link' dialog).
if (dialogName == 'link') {
    // Remove the 'Target' and 'Advanced' tabs from the 'Link' dialog.
    //dialogDefinition.removeContents('target');
    //dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');

    // Get a reference to the 'Link Info' tab.
    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
    infoTab.remove('protocol');
    infoTab.get('linkType').style = 'display: none';
}
```

});

If you get rid of **Link Type** using `infoTab.remove('linkType');` it will fails to create the link